# What is the gradient of $\ln(|f|)$ for complex-valued functions $f$?

Tags: derivatives, complex-numbers, logarithms

For a complex-valued function $f$, with its complex conjugate $f^\ast$, what is the gradient of $\ln\left(\left|f\right|\right)$?

### For real-valued f

The solution is quite straight-forward, if f is real:
$$
\ln\left(\left|f\right|\right)
=\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(f^2\right)
$$
And therefore:
$$
\nabla\ln\left(\left|f\right|\right)
=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\nabla f^2}{f^2}
=\frac{1}{2}\frac{2f\nabla f}{f^2}
=\frac{\nabla f}{f}
$$
This looks a bit odd, since $\ln\left(f\right)$ has exactly the same gradient. But keep in mind, that $\ln\left(f\right)$ is only defined, where $f>0$ and thus $\left|f\right|=f$.

### For complex-valued f

For complex valued f, there are different ways to approach this:

#### 1st option

$$
\ln\left(\left|f\right|\right)
=\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\left|f\right|^2\right)
$$
And therefore:
$$
\nabla\ln\left(\left|f\right|\right)
=\frac{1}{2}\nabla\ln\left(\left|f\right|^2\right)
=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\nabla\left|f\right|^2}{\left|f\right|^2}
=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\nabla\left(f^\ast f\right)}{\left|f\right|^2}
=\frac{1}{2}\frac{f^\ast\nabla f+f\nabla f^\ast}{\left|f\right|^2}
$$

#### 2nd option

$$
\ln\left(\left|f\right|\right)
=\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\left|f\right|^2\right)
=\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(f^\ast f\right)
=\frac{1}{2}\left[\ln\left(f^\ast\right)+\ln\left(f\right)\right]
$$
And therefore:
$$
\nabla\ln\left(\left|f\right|\right)
=\frac{1}{2}\left[\nabla\ln\left(f^\ast\right)\nabla\ln\left(f\right)\right]
=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\nabla f^\ast}{f^\ast}+\frac{\nabla f}{f}\right)
=\Re\left(\frac{\nabla f}{f}\right)
$$

#### What is happening?

Now, these two solutions are not identical, but for real $f$, both give the real solution. I'd intuitively go with the first one, since the second one seems odd (with the imaginary part disappearing). **Which one should I take?**

Comment: Note that $$\frac{1}{2}\frac{f^\ast\nabla f+f\nabla f^\ast}{\left|f\right|^2} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\nabla f^\ast}{f^\ast}+\frac{\nabla f}{f}\right)$$ so both options give the same result, contrary to your claim.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out! Isn't it odd, that the Imaginary part of $\nabla f/f$ simply disappears? And could you make it into an answer, that I can accept?

Comment: Why should it be odd? The result *must* be real.

Comment: Yes, but for instance $|f|^2=\Re(f)^2 + \Im(f)^2$ is also real, but the imaginary part does not simply disappear. I always think, that there should be no preference regarding the real or imaginary part of a complex number.

Comment: yes, I fixed the question. I don't know, why I introduced the minus...

Comment: $\frac{1}{2}\left[\nabla\ln\left(f^\ast\right)\nabla\ln\left(f\right)\right]
$ should probably be $\frac{1}{2}\left[\nabla\ln\left(f^\ast\right)+\nabla\ln\left(f\right)\right]
$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes no difference. Let $U$ be any disk on which $f$ is nonzero, and let $\log(f)$, $\log(f^*)$ be any continuous branches of their logarithms on $U$. Then
$$
 \exp(\log(f) + \log(f^*)) = \exp(\log(f)) \cdot \exp( \log(f^*))  = f f^* = |f|^2 \, ,
$$
and therefore
$$
\log(|f|^2) = \log(f) + \log(f^*) + k 2 \pi i
$$
on $U$, for some integer constant $k$. So your second method gives
$$ \require{cancel}
\nabla \log(|f|) = \frac 12\nabla \log(|f|^2) = \frac 12\nabla \bigl( \log(f) + \log(f^*) + k 2 \pi i\bigr) \\
= \frac 12 \left( \frac{\nabla f}{f} + \frac{\nabla f^*}{f^*}\right) + \cancel{\nabla(k \pi i)}
= \frac 12 \frac{f^* \nabla f + f \nabla f^*}{|f|^2}
$$
and that is the same result as the one obtained by the first method.

Now if $f$ is non-zero on an arbitrary domain, the above calculations shows that both methods give the same result at every point in the domain, no matter which branch of the logarithm is chosen *locally.*

Comment: thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Since $\nabla\log\left(\left|f\right|\right)=\Re\left(\frac{\nabla f}{f}\right)$, what about
$\nabla\log\left(\mathrm{sgn}\left(f\right)\right)=i\Im\left(\frac{\nabla f}{f}\right)$?

Comment: What should $\operatorname{sgn}(f)$ be for a complex-valued function? And for real-valued functions it would normally not be differentiable. So that makes no sense IMO.

Comment: I thought
$$
\mathrm{sgn}(f) = \frac{f}{|f|}=\sqrt\frac{f^2}{f^\ast f}=\sqrt\frac{f}{f^\ast}
$$
and therefore
$$
\nabla\log(\mathrm{sgn}(f))=\frac{1}{2}\nabla\log\frac{f}{f^\ast}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{f^\ast}{f}\nabla\frac{f}{f^\ast}=i\Im\left(\frac{\nabla f}{f}\right)
$$
But yeah, this is very bad math, taking the log of a potentially negative number...
I just wondered how to get the missing part of $\frac{\nabla f}{f}$.

Comment: It also is somehow consistent with
$$
f=|f|\operatorname{sgn}(f)
$$
And therefore
$$
\nabla\log(f)=\nabla\log(|f|)+\nabla\log(\operatorname{sgn}(f))=\Re\left(\frac{\nabla f}{f}\right)+i\Im\left(\frac{\nabla f}{f}\right)=\frac{\nabla f}{f}
$$
But probably all of this is abuse of notation. I am not very familiar with the complex logarithm...

Answer (score 2):

I'd argue the following way: with the 1st option, we only use the logarithm of real numbers, while we need the logarithm of complex numbers in the 2nd option ($\ln\left(f\right)$ and $\ln\left(f^\ast\right)$ appear).

The logarithm is known to be ill-defined for complex numbers, since it has infinitely many solutions (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm)). Treating it like the real logarithm, one often runs into problems, e.g.:
$$
\begin{aligned}
e^{2\pi i} &= 1\qquad |\ln\\
2\pi i &= 0\qquad ???
\end{aligned}
$$
**It is therefore valid to just go for the first option, since it uses only the well-defined logarithm of real numbers.**

Comment: The multi-valued-ness of the logarithm is *not* a problem here, because an additive constant “vanishes” after differentiation. As mentioned above, it does not matter which approach you use.

Comment: Excellent answer and welcome to this site, Libavius: +1. And it is indeed a capital sin to write $\ln (f )$ when $f$ is a complex valued function.